# Why is my code throwing a SIGBUS error, even when I store variables in heap?

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, heap-memory

In the method `plotThermalNoise()` of the `Antenna` class, for some reason the `for` loop does not run. Initially, I used `int` for `n` and `i`, however I need to work with much larger numbers than `int` can hold. SO, now I'm using a `long int` for both. The program no longer works, however. I stepped through it with GDB, and it seems I'm getting a SIGBUS error. I tried using `new` so as to store both variables in heap, however the loop still doesn't run.

```
#define k 0.0000000000000000000000138064852 //Boltzmann's constant

class Antenna{

    double _srate, _sdur, _res, _temp, _band;

    public:
        Antenna(double sampling_rate, double sample_duration, double resistance_ohms, double temperature_kelvin, double bandwidth_Hz){
            _srate = sampling_rate;     _sdur = sample_duration;
            _res   = resistance_ohms;   _temp = temperature_kelvin;
            _band  = bandwidth_Hz;
        }


        void plotThermalNoise();
};

void Antenna::plotThermalNoise(){

    //calculate RMS, mean of Gaussian
    double RMS =  sqrt(4 * _res * k * _temp * _band);
    double V   =  sqrt((4 * k * _temp * _band) / _res);

    long int n = _srate / _sdur;
    double x[*n],y[*n];
    
    gRandom->SetSeed(time(NULL));

    for(long int i = 0; i < n; ++i){

        x[i] = i;
        y[i] = gRandom->Gaus(V,RMS);

    }

    TGraph gr = new TGraph(n,x,y);
    gr->SetTitle("Thermal Noise Voltage vs Time Trace;Seconds;Volts");
    gr->Draw();

}

void dataAquisitionSim(){     

    Antenna test(4000000000, 0.000001, 50, 90, 500);
    test.plotThermalNoise();    

}
```

Comment: Let's see, 4E9 divided by 1E-6 gives 4E15. That's an awful lot of integers to store.

Comment: `long int n = ...; double x[*n],y[*n];` - does that compile??

Comment: Consider using a `std::vector` instead of those arrays.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, however, this doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
    long int n = _srate / _sdur;
    double x[*n],y[*n];
```

This code will not compile. I assume your *actual* code is:

```
    long int n = _srate / _sdur;
    double x[n],y[n];
```

With the parameters you pass in: `4000000000` for `_srate` and `0.000001` for `_sdur`, `n` becomes `4,000,000,000 / 0.000,000,1 == 4,000,000,000,000,000`.

You then attempt to allocate two `double` arrays of that size on stack. The total size of these arrays is 64 *peta*-bytes.

The largest super-computer [currently in existence](https://www.ornl.gov/news/ornl-launches-summit-supercomputer) has "over 10PiB of memory". So you only need something mere 6 times larger than that.

> it seems I'm getting a SIGBUS error.

As you *should*. Some back of the envelope calculations should help you realize that just because your code compiles doesn't mean it will run.

> even when I store variables in heap?

Unless you *actually* have a computer with more than 64PiB of RAM, stack vs. heap is irrelevant -- you'll run out of either.